# Is invocable and ambiguous call: bug in either g++ or clang

Tags: c++, c++17, ambiguous, compiler-bug, diamond-problem

Consider the following code:

```
// Preamble
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

// A base class
template <class T>
struct base {void operator()(T){};};

// Two derived classes inheriting from the same base classes
template <class... T>
struct derived1: base<T>... {using base<T>::operator()...;};
template <class... T>
struct derived2: base<T>... {using base<T>::operator()...;};

// A class inheriting from both derived1 and derived2
template <class T0, class... T>
struct functor: derived1<T0>, derived2<T0, T...> {
    using derived1<T0>::operator();
    using derived2<T0, T...>::operator();
};

// Main function
int main() {
    std::cout << std::is_invocable_v<functor<int, float, char>, int> << "\n";
    std::cout << std::is_invocable_v<functor<int, float, char>, float> << "\n";
    std::cout << std::is_invocable_v<functor<int, float, char>, char> << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

The call to `functor<int, float, char>::operator()(int)` is ambiguous because this operator is inherited twice, from both `derived1` and `derived2` (and let's say that for convoluted SFINAE purpose I want it to be ambiguous).

On `clang++-5.0`, the output of the code is `0`, `1`, `1`, while on `g++-7.2` the output is `1`, `1`, `1`. Which one is right? And would there be a workaround, creating a new `struct is_unambiguously_invocable` while waiting for the bugfix?

Comment: @Barry - interesting; another way to reproduce the bug pre-C++17: tring to implement a custom `isInvocableF()` as follows: `template <typename F, typename ... Args> constexpr std::false_type isInvocableF (...) { return {}; } template <typename F, typename ... Args> constexpr auto isInvocableF (int) -> decltype( std::declval<F>()(std::declval<Args>()...), std::true_type{} ) { return {}; }`. Following your example, calling `isInvocableF<f, int>(0)` you get 1 (`std::true_type`) from g++, 0 (`std::false_type`) from clang++.

Comment: @Barry Don't answer in comments; you are leaving questions in the unanswered C++17 queue!

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont As you wish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct. Note that gcc correctly disallows the call itself:

```
functor<int, float, char>()(42); // error: base<int> is an ambiguous base
```

It just incorrectly detects that this invocation is ill-formed. Reported this as [gcc bug 84869](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=84689). T.C. added a further reduced reproduction in the bug report that does not have library dependencies:

> ```
> struct base {
>     void operator()(int ) { }
> };
>
> struct a : base { };
> struct b : base { };
>
> struct f: a, b {
>     using a::operator();
>     using b::operator();
> };
>
> template<class T> auto g(int) -> decltype(T()(0), 0);
> template<class T> auto g(...) -> long;
>
> template<class, class> struct Same;
> template<class T> struct Same<T, T> {};
>
> Same<decltype(g<f>(0)), long> s; // should be okay, but gcc errors because it
>                                  // thinks decltype(g<f>(0)) is int
> ```